# Ask for open input

Tags: facebook, facebook-messenger, messenger

I've just started with the facebook messenger platform. And while it seems that quite a lot is possible. I've had trouble figuring out how to ask for open input.

The idea is this: the user sends us a key word, this works and the bot asks for an ID with which it could fetch additional data. The only problem is how do I capture this ID and start the fetch process with it? How do I let the bot know that the next reply from the user should be used for this process?

I tried some things with the payloads, but no succes so far, only crashes or the bot just follows the generic message received method (which echo's the message back to the user).

Answer (score 1):

You could either use a payload to carry the information in, or instead I'd recommend keeping track of a users state, meaning every time you get a message check if they sent a keyword, and if they did, move them to the "waiting for ID state" and save the keyword along with their userId and state.

If you have specific issues with coding, such as the crash you mentioned with payloads, post the code that's causing you issues and we can try to help out.